# dynamically building an array using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have 4 checkbox in html. I want if any checkbox is checked its value is stored in array. I created a function but its shows the empty array

```js
var arry = [];

function CheckBox(check) {
  debugger

  for (i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
    if (check[i].checked == true) {
      arry.push(check[i].value);
      alert(arry);
    }
  }

}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btn").click(function() {
    debugger;
    alert(arry);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="1" class="chk" onclick="CheckBox(this)" />1
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="2" class="chk" onclick="CheckBox(this)" />2
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" value="3" class="chk" onclick="CheckBox(this)" />3
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk4" value="4" class="chk" onclick="CheckBox(this)" />4
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="alert" />
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed your snippet. Please take more care

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `.each()` to loop  the checkbox
2. Use `.is(":checked")` to check check state

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btn").click(function() {
    var arry = [];
    $.each($(".chk"), function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        arry.push($(this).val());
      }

    })
    console.log(arry)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="1" class="chk" />1
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="2" class="chk" />2
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" value="3" class="chk" />3
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk4" value="4" class="chk" />4
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="alert" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues. The worst was to not get the checkboxes in the function.

You passed one box, not an array of boxes

```js
var arry = [];  
function CheckBox(check) {
  arry = [];  
  $("."+check.className).each(function() {  // get the other checks
    if (this.checked) { // or jQuery: $(this).is(":checked");
      arry.push(this.value); // or jQuery $(this).val()
      alert(arry);
    }
  })
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btn").click(function() {
    alert(arry);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="1" class="chk" onclick="CheckBox(this)" />1
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="2" class="chk" onclick="CheckBox(this)" />2
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" value="3" class="chk" onclick="CheckBox(this)" />3
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk4" value="4" class="chk" onclick="CheckBox(this)" />4
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="alert" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following changes in you JavaScript/Jquery code

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    var arry = [];
    $.each($(".chk"), function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        arry.push($(this).val());
      }

    })
    alert(arry)
  });
});
```